# Local Notification issues in iOS

Tags: ios5, ios6, notifications, uilocalnotification

I am setting local notifications, for a particular date and time, for some rows in my table. So consider

**case 1: When the user is setting the local notifications for first time, he selects the date from date picker, which, I pass it to the local notification object firedate.**

```
NSArray *notificationarray = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduledLocalNotifications];
        if([notificationarray count]== 0)
        {
            m_alarmLocalNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
            m_alarmLocalNotification.fireDate = DateTime;
            m_alarmLocalNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

            NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:m_Name forKey:@"ID"];
            m_alarmLocalNotification.userInfo = infoDict;

            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:m_alarmLocalNotification];
```

**case2: Modifying the local notiification date.**

```
    NSArray *notificationarray  = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduledLocalNotifications];
                for (int i = 0;i < [notificationarray count];i++)
                {
                    UILocalNotification *notificationObject=[notificationarray objectAtIndex:i];
                    NSString *Name=[notificationObject.userInfo valueForKey:@"ID"];

                    if(Name isEqualToString:m_Name])
                    {
                        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notificationObject];
                    m_alarmLocalNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
                    m_alarmLocalNotification.fireDate = DateTime;
                    m_alarmLocalNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];      


                    NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:m_noteName forKey:@"ID"];
                    m_alarmLocalNotification.userInfo = infoDict;

                    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:m_alarmLocalNotification];   
                    }
                   else
                   {

                    m_alarmLocalNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
                    m_alarmLocalNotification.fireDate = DateTime;
                    m_alarmLocalNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];      


                    NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:m_noteName forKey:@"ID"];
                    m_alarmLocalNotification.userInfo = infoDict;

                    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:m_alarmLocalNotification]; 
                }         

        }
```

**Case 3: deleting the local notiification.**

```
NSArray *notificationarray =  [[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduledLocalNotifications];
        NSLog(@"notification count:%d",[notificationarray count]);
        for (int i = 0;i < [notificationarray count];i++)
        {
            UILocalNotification *notificationObject=[notificationarray objectAtIndex:i];
            NSString *Name=[notificationObject.userInfo valueForKey:@"ID"];
            if([Name isEqualToString:m_Name])
            {
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notificationObject];
            }
        }
```

Problems faced.
0) I am not sure whether I am doin it the right way.
1)The default schedulednotification array doesn't get deallocated even if I delete my app and reinstall it once again.I mean it contains some previous notifications.
2)whenever I delete my cells I want the local notification should get deleted.

Regards
Ranjit

Answer (score 0):

How about the things are going if you use below code while modification of notification

```
NSArray *notificationarray  = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
    [notificationarray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UILocalNotification *notification,NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if ([[notification.userInfo valueForKey:@"ID"] isEqual:@""]) {
            notification.fireDate = [NSDate date];
        }
    }];
```